# SharePoint Version History - “Ignore” Certain Changes and Not Report Them?

Tags: versioning

Does anyone know of a way to have the version history "ignore" and not report on changes made to certain columns?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Steven, changes to any field values are captured by a version. However, if you don't want a change in field value being reported in version history, then you can set the field property `ShowInVersionHistory` to `false`.

Comment: Nadeem, this might be EXACTLY what I need. Where do i set the field value?

Comment: You will need to do it either through code or Powershell

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You can delete specific versions but a version always captures all changes to an item.

Answer (score 0):

If you update item in code you can use SPListItem.SystemUpdate(incrementListItemVersion) method. False value in parameter does not increase version.